# Problemas com layout em versões anteriores do android Xamarin Cross Platform

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform, xamarin-forms

Estou compilando o aplicativo na versão marshmallow 6.0 e abre tudo certinho. Mas, ao compilar
em algumas versões anteriores (por exemplo na versão 5.0.2 Lollipop e 4.4.2 kitkat), o layout abre distorcido e na 4.4.2 nem loga no app, dá erro de senha, porém estou digitando corretamente.
O `custom entry` que eu criei, ele abre totalmente diferente na versão 5.0.2.
Já alterei no Minimum Android to Target para a versão 4.0 mas não adiantou.
O que posso fazer para que o layout e as funcionalidades abra corretamente nas versões anteriores ?
Como posso definir via code behind a versão minima para abrir o app ?

Versão 6.0
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Versão 5.0.2

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por cross-platform você quer dizer Xamarin Forms? Pode postar o layout que estás usando?

Comment: Isso, Xamarin Forms. Sim, vou postar @Genos

Comment: Pelo que eu sei compilar com a versão mais recente não interfere nas versões anteriores. Qual o motivo de não compilar com a versão mais atual, no seu caso 6.0?

Comment: @rubStackOverflow, ele abre na versão mais atual sim, no caso na 6.0 perfeitamente. Porém, quando vou compilar em versões anteriores a essa, abre distorcido o layout, por exemplo o custom entry. Vou publicar as imagens

Comment: @Genos estão ai as imagens